# Workflow and devliverability test not working

Tags: email, workflow, email-alert

I'm trying to send an email alert from a workflow to the record owner.  I've got the from email address on the email alert set to use an organization wide default.  I can receive messages from QA Salesforce, like when I reset an email address of a user.  My Email Deliverability access level is set to All Emails, I've checked with my IT team and they are not blocking any emails.  I run the Test Deliverability and test the workflow. I don't get any of the emails.  When I look at the email log it shows sent (D) and received(R) but the sender email address is not the org default, or the user.  It's some large string of character `dsmith=companyname.com__99kuwl576j2ehpop@1j5phlc2hj5j.j-3luavmao.sandbox.salesforce.com`

Can anyone suggest some things I can try?

Comment: if you don;t use an orgWide email address on the email alert, does the workflow send the email as expected (and it is received)?

Comment: It appears it's being sent to the aliased email address. Have you ensured the user the alert is sent to has modified their email to the correct address in your sandbox? By default salesforce updated addresses to ones that won't accidentally receive emails.